# Which are the alternatives to EICAS or ECAM?

Tags: flight-data-monitoring, ecam

I know that ECAM and EICAS are the systems for Airbus and Boeing for the monitoring of the aircraft systems. So, on a A320 there is the ECAM and on a B737 there is the EICAS. I know the differences between them and how they work. 
What I wonder is:

How do I know in a not Airbus/Boeing aircraft which is the system for the monitoring of aircraft alarms?

For example: what do I have in a AW139, or in a Gulfstream650? Is it still called ECAM or in some other ways? Is it built by the same manufacturer? Has it the same name?

Comment: For the Gulfstream at least, it is a proprietary product developed with Honeywell called [PlaneView](http://www.gulfstream.com/technology/planeview). In general, these systems are called "Electronic Flight Information Systems" or EFIS for short. For larger aircraft they are usually manufacturer specific. For smaller GA aircraft they are provided by the avionics manufacturer, like the Garmin G1000.